# Is creating separate XSD type for data item key good Web Service design, when data item can be identified by multiple attributes?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have specified like this because I want different consumers to be able to identify data differently. External consumers don't know about id and internal do.

```
<!-- all are minoccurs=0 because only data present will be updated -->
<xs:complexType name="tSomeData">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="externalname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="manufacturer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="manufacturertype" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <!-- more values -->
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="tSomeKey">
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="externalname" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="UpdateSome">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="somekey" type="tSomeKey" />
      <xs:element name="somedata" type="tSomeData" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="GetSome">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="key" type="tSomeKey" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I think more basic way is to have only 1 element for update and the key is found out from the elements. My approach

Pros: States explicitly the criteria for identification

Cons: Added complexity and verbosity.

So what you think of this approach of separating key and data?

Comment: Good .. Seems similar to "soap\wrapper style" approach [See Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-usagewsdl/)