# Is it good Web Service design to have same XSD-type for data in all CRU-operations?

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl

In update I have separate key element type to identify the object ([Is creating separate XSD type for data item key good Web Service design, when data item can be identified by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162837/is-creating-separate-xsd-type-for-data-item-key-good-web-service-design-when-da)) so all elements of separate data element type below are optional to support update of only 1-n elements.

```
<xs:complexType name="tSomeData">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="externalname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="manufacturer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
     <xs:element name="manufacturertype" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
     <xs:element name="area" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xs:element name="doublevalue" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This type is used in:

1. response of Get (all elements in response)
2. Add-request (all elements except id, because system generates it)
3. Update-request (1-n elements, only elements in request are updated, not id)

So my question is: Is this ok (because not explicitly stated what there should be in tSomeData in each operation)?

If my approach is not Ok, should I have types:

1. tSomeDataAdd (all mandatory, no id element)
2. tSomeDataUpdate (all optional, no id element)
3. tSomeDataGet (all mandatory, also id element)

(because then it would be explicitly stated what really is the data in messages)?

Having tSomeData acceptable for Get/Add/Update would help a lot in implementation and make the interface definition less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those questions that may get a different answer, depending on who you're asking, on how it is going to be implemented - from a programming language perspective, to how testing is to be conducted and deployment to be managed.

If people want to rely as much as possible on XSD validation, instead of doing it themselves in code, then "one size fits all" XSD is not going to cut it. On the other hand, if I am modeling it, and I am already late delivering it, or if a developer complains about the number of classes generated by an XSD-to-code binding tool, then might as well give them the least amount of classes; more so if there's already a document describing the business rules, and/or if the rules are so complicated that beyond a basic type system check, the XSD wouldn't do much anyway...

If your team is massive, typically on big, mission critical systems, then there's an expectation to break out everything in small pieces, for independent development and testing; it would be much easier to do with specialized models, specific to a use case. I've seen places where each operation is implemented as a standalone deployment unit, to reduce regression testing costs in mission critical systems. For these, nobody cares about the total number of classes, since each team focuses only on the little piece they've been assigned to; and less coupling there is between "the modules", the better.

Personally, I can easily manage large models; it also turned out that it is less headache than having to "sell" a multivalent model, even when it is an exercise in beauty and elegant thinking; since a model such as this would require long instruction sheets nobody will read, for various reasons, why bother?... And the funny part is that it might not make a long term difference anyway, with disposable software and all that...

There are many ways to reuse; and at different levels in a larger model; for what you've described, I would go with three different types.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tend to agree with you because as I said, looking the schema you see what you should have in messages. I still might have only 1 type unless somebody explains why it would be totally horrible thing to do :) Thanks especially for different viewpoints.